# Make preferences changes take effect immediately from CLI

Tags: system-settings, defaults

How you can make changes take effect and update in the Preferences GUI immediately without having to reboot (unacceptable), log out (bad) or kill processes (last resort)? macOS 10.12

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool NO
sudo defaults write /var/db/locationd/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.locationd.plist LocationServicesEnabled -bool NO
```

Update:

- Restarting Finder updates swipe GUI, but not the swiping itself! *How can this be done?*
- Location services: Updates instantly now. (Must have been something wrong before.)

Comment: I think you need to restart the "finder.app"  for any UI changes to take place.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of macOS you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Send the System Preferences process a signal called the 'hang-up' or HUP, also known as signal number 1 as defined somewhere in a system signals.h header file. POSIX convention, I believe.

The quick and dirty:

```
sudo pkill -1 'System Preferences'
```

Replace System Preferences with Finder, or the PID of a relevant process.  Another quick and dirty:

```
for STALE in Finder Preferences locationd ; do sudo pkill -1 $( pgrep ${STALE} ) ; done
```

What a HUP signal should effectuate in the receiving process is an internal halt and re-evaluation, which usually includes a re-reading of any relevant config files. The process will not terminate, only 'refresh' itself.

Hope this helps.

F.

Comment: Interesting! I have never heard of this before. Did you try that it's working as described, ie. re-reading configuration without terminating? (Also, what is the scope of this practice? Is it something that applies for many/most Linux/Apple apps?)

Comment: My friend, if memory serves me well, signals were standardized across all UNIX platforms under one of the POSIX standards, a long time ago.  It is convention and expected behavior that a process re-evaluate its configuration files upon receiving a HUP signal.  I have not tested this on Mac OS, yet the shell code is valid and works to send HUPS to the Finder, locationd, and Systems Preferences.  F.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with some background. I will test this upon next chance!

Comment: The fact that I am familiar with the POSIX conventions is merely a testament to my old age and relevant experience... ;-|

Comment: Preferences does not handle HUP and just terminates.